# Random 2d Polygon with holes like a map of a building

Tags: random, polygon

i am searching an algorithm which generates a simple polygon with holes.

It should look like a plan of a building or something like that

do you now some algorithm in c++ or python

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constrained delaunay triangulation. Just create a delaunay triangulation and then remove the vertex with the holes and replace it with new vertex and edges.